# How to prevent LD_PRELOAD on a binary?

Tags: c, linux, hook, ld-preload

I write binary in C code.  How can I prevent another user from using `LD_PRELOAD` on my binary?

When using `LD_PRELOAD`, is there any signal that I can handle and break the program?

If I compile the binary statically, I heard that `LD_PRELOAD` will not work, right?

Is there another way?

Comment: You can check whether the LD_PRELOAD environment variable is set. But they could link in a different version of `getenv()` to make this difficult.

Comment: Why do you care about this?

Comment: Pretty much a cross-site dupe: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/63599/is-there-any-way-to-block-ld-preload-and-ld-library-path-on-linux

Comment: @Barmar can you please explain that more? When process running with `LD_PRELOAD` is that environment variable to process? How can I check that ,and witch kind of environment variable can be set?

Comment: Will these user's be able to hex-edit the binary you give them?  Or run it under something like `dtrace`?

Answer (score 4):

Just like scripts have an interpreter specified via the `#!` mechanism, excecutables work similarly. ELF executables have a field in the program header whose type is `PT_INTERP` and it gives a path to an "interpreter" for the executable. That "interpreter" is the dynamic linker, `ld-linux.so`. That linker will process the header and map the file into memory and all the rest.

It is this `ld-linux.so` loader that implements the `LD_PRELOAD` feature.

If you produce a custom version of this program in which support for `LD_PRELOAD` is removed or disabled, and then point your executable's program header to use that `ld-linux.so` instead of the usual one as its "interpreter", you should be able to defeat `LD_PRELOAD`.

> *If I compile the binary statically, I heard that LD_PRELOAD will not work, right?*

While that is basically true, static linking is not supported on Glibc. Today, if you want to distribute a statically linked executable, you're looking at using an alternative C library [like Musl](https://www.musl-libc.org/intro.html): *"Designed from the ground up for static linking, musl carefully avoids pulling in large amounts of code or data that the application will not use."*

Answer (score 1):

ld preload is used by setting the `LD_PRELOAD` environment variable when running the program. So your program can check for this.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argv, char *argv) {
    if (getenv("LD_PRELOAD")) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Sorry, you can't use ld preload with this program.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    ...
}
```

This will work unless the preloaded library supplies its own `getenv()` that hides this variable.

Comment: but LD_PRELOAD can also "preload" getenv() though.

Comment: I know, I mentioned it in a comment above. I've added it to the answer.